# Grouping related rows of data into a single column in Linux

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a csv file that gets generated daily and automatically that has output similar to the following example:

```
"N","3.5",3,"Bob","10/29/17" 
"Y","4.5",5,"Bob","10/11/18" 
"Y","5",6,"Bob","10/28/18" 
"Y","3",1,"Jim", 
"N","4",2,"Jim","09/29/17" 
"N","2.5",4,"Joe","01/26/18"
```

I need to transform the text so that it is grouped by person (the fourth column), and all of the records are in a single row and in the columns are repeated using the same sequence:  1,2,3,5.  Some cells may be missing data but must remain in the sequence so the columns line up.  So the output I need will look like this:

```
"Bob","N","3.5",3,"10/29/17","Y","4.5",5,"10/11/18","Y","5",6,"10/28/18"
"Jim","Y","3",1,,"N","4",2,"09/29/17"
"Joe","N","2.5",4,"01/26/18"
```

I am open to using sed, awk, or pretty much any standard Linux command to get this task done.  I've been trying to use awk, and though I get close, I can't figure out how to finish it.

Here is the command where I'm close.  It lists the header and the names, but no other data:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1; NR>1 {a[$4]=a[$4] ? i : ""} END {for (i in a) {print i}}' test2.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need little more code

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
             {k=$4; $4=$5; NF--; a[k]=(k in a?a[k] FS $0:$0)} 
       END   {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file

"Bob","N","3.5",3,"10/29/17" ,"Y","4.5",5,"10/11/18" ,"Y","5",6,"10/28/18" 
"Jim","Y","3",1, ,"N","4",2,"09/29/17" 
"Joe","N","2.5",4,"01/26/18"
```

note that `NF--` trick may not work in all `awk`s.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following too, reading the Input_file 2 times, it will provide output in same sequence in which 4th column has come in Input_file.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$4]=a[$4]?a[$4] OFS $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $5:$4 OFS $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $5
  next
}
a[$4]{
  print a[$4]
  delete a[$4]
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance that any of the CSV values has a comma, then a "CSV-aware" tool will would be advisable to obtain a reliable but straightforward solution.

One approach would be to use one of the many readily available csv2tsv command-line tools.  A variety of elegant solutions then becomes possible.  For example, one could pipe the CSV into csv2tsv, awk, and tsv2csv.

Here is another solution that uses csv2tsv and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
csv2tsv < input.csv | jq -Rrn '
  [inputs | split("\t")]
  | group_by(.[3])[]
  | sort_by(.[2])
  | [.[0][3]] + ( map( del(.[3])) | add)
  | @csv
'
```

This produces:

```
"Bob","N","3.5","3","10/29/17 ","Y","4.5","5","10/11/18 ","Y","5","6","10/28/18 "
"Jim","Y","3","1"," ","N","4","2","09/29/17 "
"Joe","N","2.5","4","01/26/18"
```

Trimming the excess spaces is left as an exercise :-)